# How to provide External Configuration resources (Database properties and XML files) to classpath in Spring Boot linux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been facing the issue with external configuration files to the classpath in spring boot, But it's not picking **application.properties, application-dev properties from the external config folder**. It's picking the database properties and XML files from the external config folder.I have tried the below approaches, can you please help me to resolve this issue.

> java -cp ./config/*;./lib/ips--0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   java  -cp ./config/*;./lib/ips-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   java -jar ./lib/ips-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/config/,file:./config/,classpath:/,file:./

```
@ImportResource("classpath:ips-spring.xml")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { KafkaAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(value = "com.mark", useDefaultFilters = false)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationRest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRest.class, args);
        System.out.println("Started ApplicationRest");
    }
}

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:env.properties,classpath:db.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="false" ignore-unresolvable="false" />
<import resource="classpath:app-entity.xml" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `@PropertySource`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "external configurations" you mean the configuration files (`*.properties`, `*.yml`, etc) that are not packaged into the spring boot artifact (Jar in your example)

In this case, they are by definition not in the `classpath` of the application.

So to paraphrase, you are asking how to supply external configuration files to spring application. As you've found out already, indeed `--spring.config.location` is the way to go:

```
--spring.config.location=file:/work/config1.yml,file:/work/config2.yml
```

Comment: I am executing a spring boot jar with below command. But it's not picking the db.properties,env.properties from the external config folder. I have given the --spring.config.location in execute cmd.  But it's not picking the db.properties from outside of the jar.  java  -cp /home/ips/ips-rest/config:/home/ips/ips-rest/config/:/home/ips/ips-rest/config/*  -jar ips-rest-0.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/ips-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: You don't need a -cp. Spring boot itself contains pretty complicated classpath structure that is not really consistent with the classpath of java. Run java -jar ips-rest.jar --spring.config.location=...

Comment: Hi I have tried with below ways. It's picking only application.properties from external config folder, it's not picking other property files.............................java -jar ./lib/ips-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=./config/db.properties     java -jar ./lib/ips-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/config/,file:./config/,classpath:/,file:./        java -jar ./lib/ips-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.additional-location=classpath:./config/,file:///./config/